# How to add WMS layer in OpenLayers from GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers-2

How to overlay a WMS layer from GeoServer (localhost)in OpenLayers?

What is the basic syntax of a GeoServer WMS layer?

Details are as follows:

workspace name: india
layer name:hospitals

```
 <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
 var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map'); 
 var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", "labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0";, {layers: 'basic'} );
 var twms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "World Map", "localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1& request=GetCapabilities&", 
 { 
     map: 'hospitals', 
     transparent: 'true', 
     layers: 'hospitals'
 } ); 
 map.addLayers([wms, twms]);
 map.zoomToMaxExtent(); 
 </script>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have you tried this sample: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wms.html

Comment: Ya i tried the basic wms layer, now i want to overlay my layers from geoserver . what me to do?

Comment: please post the code that you have already used, and let us know where you are stuck right now.

Comment: Please edit your question and put it there, instead of in a comment. Also, what is the url of your geoserver?

Comment: GeoServer WMS layers conform to the WMS specification, so any OpenLayers example with any service providing a WMS should help you.  Your comment `i tried the basic wms layer, now i want to overlay my layers from geoserver` doesn't make any sense.  There should be no syntax difference.  If it's not working for you, and you are hosting the GeoServer WMS service, perhaps you should look first at getting your WMS working first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your OpenLayers.Layer.WMS statements should look like this:

```
basemap = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Layer Name1",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/workspacename", {layers: 'workspacename:layername'} );\
utility = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Layer Name2",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/workspacename", {layers: 'workspacename:layername', transparent:"true"}, {isBaseLayer:false} );
```

Comment: i want add one layer, is it sufficient the follow code?               basemap = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Layer Name1",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/workspacename", {layers: 'workspacename:layername'} );

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the version of the your API. Also define suitable projection for your layer.

```
var layer2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(maplayer.displayName,
                maplayer.datasource,
                { layers: [2], version: '1.3.0' ,'srs':maplayer.crs},
                  {singleTile: true,
                      isBaseLayer: false,
                      projection: "EPSG:102113"
                  }
                );

layer2.setOpacity(0.52);

map.addLayer(layer2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough removing '? service=wms& version=1.1.1& request=GetCapabilities' from the url parameter of the layer declaration

Answer (score 0):

Test WMS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href: "http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css"  />   
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href: "C:/ol3_samples/assests/css/samples.css" type="text/css" /> -->
```

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol.js" >

```
var wms_source = new ol.source.TileWMS({
 url: 'http://localhost:6080/geoserver/Jharkhand/wms',
 params: {
          'LAYERS': 'Jharkhand:Jharkhand_block_boundary1'
          }
          });
var wms_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
   source:  wms_source
     });       

var base_map = new ol.layer.Tile({
   source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
    });

    var layers = [
    base_map,
    wms_layer
    ];

    var vw=new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([85.6082,23.7175], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom:6
      });

     var map= new ol.Map({
     target: 'map',
     layers: layers,
     view: vw
     });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```